# webExtentions - Can't get my html templete using ajax

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

this code works on chrome but not on firefox

```
  $.get(chrome.extension.getURL("about.html"), function(d) {

        me.aboutTpl = d
    })
```

does anyone have any clue?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you get an error or something in the browser console?

Comment: have you tried cutting jquery or whatever library that is out of the equation? I.e. try a plain XHR.